# How do you do simple string concatenation in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.11

I must be being incredibly stupid but I can't figure out how to do simple string concatenation in Terraform.

I have the following data `null_data_source`:

```
data "null_data_source" "api_gw_url" {
    inputs = {
      main_api_gw = "app.api.${var.env_name == "prod" ? "" : var.env_name}mydomain.com"
    }
}
```

So when `env_name="prod"` I want the output `app.api.mydomain.com` and for anything else - let's say `env_name="staging"` I want `app.api.staging.mydomain.com`.

But the above will output `app.api.stagingmydomain.com` <-- notice the missing dot after `staging`.

I tried concating the "." if the env_name was anything but "prod" but Terraform errors:

```
data "null_data_source" "api_gw_url" {
    inputs = {
      main_api_gw = "app.api.${var.env_name == "prod" ? "" : var.env_name + "."}mydomain.com"
    }
}
```

The error is `__builtin_StringToInt: strconv.ParseInt: parsing ""`

The [`concat()`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html#concat-list1-list2-) function in TF appears to be for lists not strings.

So as the title says: **How do you do simple string concatenation in Terraform?**

I can't believe I'm asking how to concat 2 strings together XD

**Update:**

For anyone that has a similar issue I did this *horrific* workaround for the time being:

`main_api_gw = "app.api.${var.env_name == "prod" ? "" : var.env_name}${var.env_name == "prod" ? "" : "."}mydomain.com"`

Comment: Small notice, this is true for versions prior to 0.12

Comment: @Pixel Yup, for versions > 0.12, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452011/5567066

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try Below data resource :

```
data "null_data_source" "api_gw_url" {
    inputs = {
      main_api_gw = "app.api${var.env_name == "prod" ? "." : ".${var.env_name}."}mydomain.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: The newer versions might get warning for this syntax. Also consider using the string functions, please check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452011/5567066

Comment: move a dot outside the expression to simplify: `"app.api.${var.env_name == "prod" ? "" : "${var.env_name}."}mydomain.com"`

Answer (score 151):

I know this was already answered, but I wanted to share my favorite:

```
format("%s/%s",var.string,"string2")
```

Real world example:

```
locals {
 documents_path = "${var.documents_path == "" ? format("%s/%s",path.module,"documents") : var.documents_path}" 
}
```

More info:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/format.html

Comment: Any reason why would this solution be better than using ${} as mentioned in @Markus answer?

Comment: Format is way more powerful than the other $"" notation, it supports much more than just string and handles complex conversions etc, so that's the reason one could say it's better to know about it, but I am using the $ in most cases.

Answer (score 107):

so to add a simple answer to a simple question:

- enclose all strings you want to concatenate into one pair of `""`
- reference variables inside the quotes with `${var.name}`

Example: `var.foo` should be concatenated with `bar` string and separated by a dash

Solution:  `"${var.foo}-bar"`

Answer (score 52):

For Terraform 0.12 and later, you can use `join()` function:

```
join(separator, list)
```

Example:

```
> join(", ", ["foo", "bar", "baz"])
foo, bar, baz
> join(", ", ["foo"])
foo
```

If you just want to concatenate without a separator like "foo"+"bar" = "foobar", then:

```
> join("", ["foo", "bar"])
foobar
```

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/join.html

Use the [Interpolation Syntax](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/interpolation.html) for versions < 0.12

Comment: I've used this approach for multiline strings so that I can put each array element on its own line for readability (and a good diff in git).

You can't do string interpolation across multiple lines and I like `join()` better than doing `%s` a dozen times with string format.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example:

```
output "s3_static_website_endpoint" {
  value = "http://${aws_s3_bucket.bucket_tf.website_endpoint}"
}
```

Reference the Terraform Interpolation docs:
https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/strings#string-templates

Answer (score 1):

after lot of research, It finally worked for me. I was trying to follow https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-0-12-preview-first-class-expressions/, but it did not work. Seems string can't be handled inside the expressions.

```
data "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["${var.old_cluster_fqdn == "" ? "${var.cluster_fqdn}" : "${var.old_cluster_fqdn}"}-vpc"]
    
  }
}
```