# Passing certificate arn to ingress annotation using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, kubernetes-ingress, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

**Background**

Hi all,
Terraform newbie here.

I'm trying to poll an existing AWS certificate ARN and use that value  in my ingress.tf file ingress object annotation.

As a first step, I tried to poll the value using the below terraform code:

```
  # get-certificate-arn.tf
  data "aws_acm_certificate" "test" {
  domain   = "test.example.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
  }
  output "test" {
  value = data.aws_acm_certificate.test.*.arn
  description = "TESTING"
  }
```

When I run this code, it gives me my certificate ARN back (YEY!) like the example below:

```
Changes to Outputs:
  + debugging = [
      + [
          + "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:1234567890:certificate/12345abc-123-456-789def-12345etc",
]
```

**Question:**

I'd like to take this to the next level and use the output from above to feed the ingress annotations as shown by "???" in the code below:

```
# ingress.tf
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "test_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "test-ingress"
    namespace = "default"

    annotations = {
      "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn"      = ????
      ...etc...
    }
  }
```

I've tried:
`"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn"      = data.aws_acm_certificate.test.*.arn`
which doesn't work but I can't quite figure out how to pass the value from the get-certificate-arn.tf "data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn" to the ingress.tf file.

The error I get is:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│
│   on ingress.tf line 6, in resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "test_ingress":
│    6:     annotations = {
│    9:       "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn"      = data.aws_acm_certificate.test.*.arn
        [...truncated...]
│   16:     }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_acm_certificate.test is object with 11 attributes
│
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "annotations": element "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn": string required.
```

If anyone could advise how (IF?!) one can pass a variable to kubernetes_ingress_v1 'annotations' that would be amazing. I'm still learning Terraform and am still reviewing the fundamentals of passing variables around.

Comment: What is the error? Are the files at the same level, e.g., root module or they are part of different modules?

Comment: All .tf files are in the same directory. I've edited my question with a bit more detail, thank you.

Comment: Ok, so this `data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn` outputs what? It shouldn't be a list of lists, at least that's what I think.

Comment: data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn outputs the ARN of the certificate. I imagine you and @Mor Yosef are correct in that I'll have to build my annotation block a different way.

Comment: Yup, but it's a simple change, just use `"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn"      = data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the solution was a typo in the data field, removing the "*" resolved the issue. For interests sake, if you want to combine two certificates to an ingress annotation you can join them as shown here[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312783/how-do-you-do-simple-string-concatenation-in-terraform):

```
"alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn"      = format("%s,%s",data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn,data.aws_acm_certificate.test2.arn)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried maybe using :

```
"${data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn}"
```

or alternatively
you can build the whole annotations block as a local

```
local{
 ingress_annotations = {
   somekey  = somevalue
   some_other_key  = data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn
}
```

and using it in the resource

```
annotations = local.ingress_annotations
```

I'm not that keen on TF
but you might need to have a more complex setup with a for loop.

```
local{
 ingress_annotations = [
   {key  = value } ,{key = data.aws_acm_certificate.test.arn}
   ]
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "test_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "test-ingress"
    namespace = "default"

    annotations = {for line in local.ingress_annotations : line.key => line.value
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's probably a typo in your answer, you have `key` defined two times in the local variable.

Comment: it was the word 'key' as an example,
it should be replace with something else, i have edited the post and replaced key , key to , somekey, some_other_key

Comment: Sure, but that's an important thing for someone to test your solution. You also haven't changed the for loop and the second occurrence of the local variable.

Comment: @MarkoE Please write a proper answer, I'm not too experienced and I trust you will provide a solution to this issue,
I'm just not 100% sure on the syntax