# How do you read yaml environment variables in Terragrunt

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code, terragrunt

I have an `envrionment.yaml` inside my repo as config for terragrunt, which looks like something like this:

```
sandpit:
  vpc_id: vpc-123456
  acc_id: "acc123456"

nonprod:
  vpc_id: vpc-78910
  acc_id: "acc78910"
```

now in my terragrunt files (`terragrunt.hcl`) I load/read this `yaml` and try to do this:

```
...

locals {
  function_name = "my fun"
  env_vars      = yamldecode(file("${find_in_parent_folders("environment.yaml")}"))
}

....

sg_description = "Security group for ${local.function_name} in ${get_env("TF_VAR_ENV_NAME")}"
vpc_id = "${local.env_vars.${get_env("TF_VAR_ENV_NAME")}.vpc_id}"
ingress = ....
```

Note that this input variable is coming from GitHub action, and the line starting with `sg_description` which created a string with this variable works fine.  This `${get_env('TF_VAR_ENV_NAME')}` is our env name (`sandpit` or `nonprod`).

However, the next line `vpc_id = "${local.env_vars.${get_env('TF_VAR_ENV_NAME')}.vpc_id}"` does not work. I have tested [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312783/how-do-you-do-simple-string-concatenation-in-terraform) but couldn't help.

What I want to achieve is this:

```
vpc_id = "${local.env_vars.sandpit.vpc_id}"
```

So I can use relevant variables. (if I hardcord the above, the whole thing works)

The error from Action is this:
[image]

Comment: It will depend on the value of `TF_VAR_ENV_NAME`.

Comment: what do you mean, that value is a string, inputted from github workflow to terragrunt

Comment: Ah, ok, my bad, but I don't think it will work like that because terraform has its own interpolation syntax.

Comment: what's other ways to do that?

Comment: based on the link I shared you can do things like this: `main_api_gw = "app.api${var.env_name == "prod" ? "." : ".${var.env_name}."}mydomain.com"`

Comment: But `var.env_name` is a variable defined in terraform, not GitHub actions.

Comment: That shouldn't matter I believe, I can concat this with any other local var in terraform. The issue comes when I put it inside {}

Comment: Ok then, are there any errors in the GitHub actions output? If so, add them to the question.

Comment: I did and edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used this `"${local.env_vars[get_env("TF_VAR_ENV_NAME")]["vpc_id"]}"` and it worked. So in my example it would be:

```
...

locals {
  function_name = "my fun"
  env_vars      = yamldecode(file("${find_in_parent_folders("environment.yaml")}"))
}

....

sg_description = "Security group for ${local.function_name} in ${get_env("TF_VAR_ENV_NAME")}"
vpc_id = "${local.env_vars[get_env("TF_VAR_ENV_NAME")]["vpc_id"]}"
ingress = ....
```

Seams simple now I see it :)